# Firefox Unwanted Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, scroll

I have this problem on one of my project pages.

When I test the page on Firefox browser I discover that the horizontal scroll-bar is enabled where I can scroll horizontally with the same width of the page taking into consideration that the problem is appearing only on Firefox.

Any recommendations?

Here is the page that I am working on.

http://www.iagha.com/asdqwezxc/contactUs.php

And below are some pictures to describe my case!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `text-indent` on the `send` input button, in the last row of your table for the contact form. It's currently set to `2000px` - set this to `-2000px` and the horizontal scrollbar will disappear in Firefox.